# what is the use of $this->uri->segment(3) in codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

hear is my code

```
public function viewdeletedrecords()
{   

    if($this->session->userdata('applicant_firstname') == '')
    {
        redirect('papplicant/login') ;
    }
    $profile = $this->m_applicant->showdeletedrecods('','');                                                         
    $total_rows = count($profile) ;
    $config['base_url'] =  base_url().'index.php/papplicant/viewdeletedrecords/' ;
    $config['per_page'] = '10' ;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div>' ;

    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>' ;

    $config['first_link'] = 'First' ;

    $config['last_link'] = 'Last' ;

    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE ;

    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;' ;

    $config['uri_segment'] = 3 ;

    $config['num_links'] = 10 ;         

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b>' ;

    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>' ;

    $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows ;       

    $invoicepaginate = $this->m_applicant->showdeletedrecods( $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3)) ;    

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     

    $data4 = array(                             

    'data' => $invoicepaginate                                                                                       

    ) ;

    $this->load->view('applicant', $data4);

}
```

what is the use of  `$this->uri->segment(3)` in codeigniter

whan I enter `$this->uri->segment(3);` it works as expected but when I enter `$this->uri->segment(4);` it stops working

Answer (score 60):

This provides you to retrieve information from your URI strings

```
$this->uri->segment(n); // n=1 for controller, n=2 for method, etc
```

Consider this example:

> **http://example.com/index.php/controller/action/1stsegment/2ndsegment**

it will return

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // controller
$this->uri->segment(2); // action
$this->uri->segment(3); // 1stsegment
$this->uri->segment(4); // 2ndsegment
```

Answer (score 18):

[CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) says:

> $this->uri->segment(n)
>
> Permits you to retrieve a specific segment. Where n is the segment
>   number you wish to retrieve. Segments are numbered from left to right.
>   For example, if your full URL is this:
>   http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up
>
> The segment numbers would be this:
>
> ```
> 1. news
> 2. local
> 3. metro
> 4. crime_is_up
> ```

So `segment` refers to your url structure segment. By the above example, `$this->uri->segment(3)` would be `'metro'`, while `$this->uri->segment(4)` would be `'crime_is_up'`.

Answer (score 4):

In your code `$this->uri->segment(3)` refers to the pagination `offset` which you use in your query. According to your `$config['base_url'] =  base_url().'index.php/papplicant/viewdeletedrecords/' ;`, `$this->uri->segment(3)` i.e segment 3 refers to the offset. The first segment is the `controller`, second is the `method`, there after comes the `parameters` sent to the controllers as `segments`.

Answer (score 4):

By default the function returns FALSE (boolean) if the segment does not exist. There is an optional second parameter that permits you to set your own default value if the segment is missing. For example, this would tell the function to return the number zero in the event of failure:
$product_id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

It helps avoid having to write code like this:

```
[if ($this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE)
{
    $product_id = 0;
}
else
{
    $product_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a url like this
http://www.example.com/controller/action/arg1/arg2

If you want to know what are the arguments that are being passed in this url

```
$param_offset=0;
$params = array_slice($this->uri->rsegment_array(), $param_offset);
var_dump($params);
```

Output will be:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'arg1'
  1 => string 'arg2'
```