# How to get the value uri segment in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I do not understand about `uri->segment` on CodeIgniter.
as the following example, I have a table with the fields:

```
| Id_comment | id_alat     | user         |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
|     1      |    45       | irwan        |
```

if i call `$id = $this->uri->segment(4);`
It returns the `user` field.

How do I return the `id_comment` field instead?

Comment: how your URL Looks like??

Comment: Check this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293892/what-is-the-use-of-this-uri-segment3-in-codeigniter-pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293892/what-is-the-use-of-this-uri-segment3-in-codeigniter-pagination)

Comment: @Abdulla this sample my url: http://localhost/instrumentdev/instrument/instrument/detail/CT-BSC-001

Comment: @irwanDwiyanto wht is ur base url??

Comment: base url my ip addres

Comment: please post your 'view' and 'controller' code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, your url look alike: http://localhost/yourProject/users/edit/1/john/33

So you have five parameters:

```
 1. users - the controller
 2. edit  - the function
 3. 1     - the id of user
 4. john  - the name of user
 5. 33    - the age of user
```

In your `route.php` file you should create the following route:

```
$route['users/edit/(:num)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'users/edit/$1/$2/$3;
```

Finally, in your controller you are able to access the parameters from your url by `uri->segment()` **or**..

```
public function edit($id, $name, $age)
{
   echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your URL is this `instrumentdev/instrument/instrument/detail/CT-BSC-001`

then you can get data by following method

```
$url1 = base_url(); // Site URL
$url2 = $this->uri->segment(1); // Controller - instrument
$url3 = $this->uri->segment(2); // Method - instrument
$url4 = $this->uri->segment(3); // detail
$url5 = $this->uri->segment(4); // CT-BSC-001
```

Comment: yes I know but I want to call segment (5) is the value id_comment ??

Comment: so you have to pass that in ur URL

Comment: how ? if you can help me? make the script .
The script to remove comments based id_comment

Answer (score 0):

//control

```
function deletecom() {
    $u = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->mcrud->deletecomment($u);
    redirect('instrument/instrument');
}
```

//view

Answer (score 0):

Since CodeIgniter 4 this is slightly changed:

```
$uri = service('uri');
$sLast = $uri->getSegment(4, 'any default value');
```