# Does anyone know what this line of code means?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this line of code:

```
    $data['page'] =($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

I am familiar with ternary operations, but I am not very sure what this line of code does.

Comment: Yes I do!...... Look up Ternary operator in the manual

Comment: `if ($this->uri->segment(3) == true) { $data['page']=$this->uri->segment(3)} else {$data['page']=0;}`

Comment: you can check this question's answer here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293892/what-is-the-use-of-this-uri-segment3-in-codeigniter-pagination

Comment: In your ternary operator condition not exist so use like this
$data['page'] = !empty($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($this->uri->segment(3)){
    $data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
} else {
    $data['page'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if `$this->uri->segment(3)` evaluates to something that isn't false, then `$data['page']` will be set to its content, otherweise to 0.

you'd know that if you actually knew ternary operations, as you stated.

it's a very common way to establish a default value for a variable.

Comment: Actually what I don't understand is the $this->uri->segment(3) part

Comment: then you should have said so in the first place. look at the class your code is in, it should contain a method called `uri`, and look what the code does.

Comment: $this->uri->segment(3) since by default CI uses slashes and not query strings each each value after a slash represets a  segment so the above code is nothing but fetching the 3rd segment in your uri

Answer (score 0):

`$this->uri->segment(3)` seems to return a page number, if possible.

The condition checks if the result is true (a valid number > 0 is also true) and assigns the result to `$data['page']`. If the result in unexpected or invalid (most likely false or null in this scenario) 0 gets applied instead.

This ensures that `$data['page']` always gets a proper value.

You could also write this:

```
$data['page'] = 0;
if (is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3)) && $this->uri->segment(3) > 0) {
    $data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = <test condition>? value to use if True, : value to use if False
```

In the case of

```
$data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

As per the userguide ( we all read that now and then... ), $this->uri->segment(3) will return the value of segment 3 of the uri if it exists, else it will return NULL.

/controller/method/parameter
Segment 1 = controller
Segment 2 = method
Segment 3 = parameter , and we can have any number of parameters after that, so you could have more segments..

So if the uri contains a Segment 3 ( ie /controller/method/parameter ), the "parameter" value would be returned as it's the 3rd segment and in the above test, it will evaluate to be Not NULL or True and $data['page'] will be set to the value defined after the ? which in this case, is itself, i.e the value of $this->uri->segment(3).

If the uri does not contain a segment 3 (ie /controller/method ), then $this->uri->segment(3) will evaluate to NULL or False and the value after the : is assigned to $data['page'], in this case 0.

So this is how you can return any value you like instead of NULL in this instance.

As per the userguide for CI 3.1.0 you can pass a 2nd parameter to perform the same task.

So instead of

```
$data['page'] =($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

You use

```
$data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(3,0);
```

Now as this example appears to be passing what appears to be a page name as the 3rd segment of the uri, going to all the trouble to alter the default or failed value from Null to 0 seems iffy.

You'll be wanting to test for this... i.e do I get a page name or don't I.
If I do, I'll get a string, so then I can see if it matches a page name I have. If I don't get a page_name, ie nothing,  I'll get a Null and when I test for that I'll do something appropriate...

If that's even more confusion I apologize!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am using $data['page'] as a parameter for this method:

Comment: public function get_all($limit,$start){
     $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
       $q=$this->db->get('users');
      $rows=array();
      foreach($q->result() as $row){
     $rows[]=$row;
        }
       return $rows;
     }