# How to properly use $this->uri->segment(n) Setting a class as active in navigation using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

seems like I missed something here in my code. I'm trying to use the uri segment for active menu in my navigation. Thanks for helping I'm kinda new to CodeIgniter I really appreciate it.

**PHP:**

```
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('home/co_landing_page');?>" 
        <?php 
          if($this->uri->segment(1)=="home/co_landing_page")
          {echo 'class="nav_active"';}
        ?>
    >Home</a>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('home/co_profile');?>" 
        <?php 
          if($this->uri->segment(1)=="home/co_profile")
          {echo 'class="nav_active"';}
        ?>
    >Profile</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.nav_active{
    color:#4f91a2;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

**Controllers:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('landing_page');
    }

    function co_landing_page(){ $this->load->view('landing_page');}
    function co_project(){ $this->load->view('project');}
    function co_profile(){ $this->load->view('profile');}
}
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/19293943/3568847 and  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html?highlight=uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('home/co_landing_page');?>" class="<?php echo ($this->uri->segment(2) == 'co_landing_page')?'nav_active':''; ?>  >Home</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('home/co_profile');?>" class="<?php echo ($this->uri->segment(2) == 'co_profile')?'nav_active':''; ?>  >Profile</a>
```

For future please read these links for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/a/19293943/3568847 and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html?highlight=uri

Comment: @Philip welcome, we all are here to help. Well no need  for a single controller but if you want or need you can use `$this->uri->segment(1) == 'home' && $this->uri->segment(2) == 'co_landing_page'`

Comment: Oh I see Thanks again @Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Do it easy way. in your HTML give identifier to your section or div like

```
<div class="slider" id="welcome-sec">
```

In your link just use like

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/controller/function#welcome-sec">
```

And you will be redirected to that section of page.

[Example](https://www.mastercook.ae/new/home/index#welcome-sec)

Comment: it's already redirecting to another page. I need to set a active in the class when a menu is selected. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `uri_string()` instead of uri_segment. The `uri_strig()` returns a string with the `complete URI`.

if you have `full URL:`

```
http://example.com/home/co_landing_page
```

The method would return this:

```
home/co_landing_page
```

SO try below:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('home/co_landing_page');?>" 
        <?php 
          if($this->uri->uri_string() =="home/co_landing_page")
          {echo 'class="nav_active"';}
        ?>
    >Home</a>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('home/co_profile');?>" 
        <?php 
          if($this->uri->uri_string() =="home/co_profile")
          {echo 'class="nav_active"';}
        ?>
    >Profile</a>
```